# What is the =stdev equivalent in R?

Tags: r, standard-deviation

I am trying to calculate the standard deviation for each participant across certain columns (or variables) and have this as a new variable in my dataframe. In Excel, it's relatively simple, you would just use =stdev and then select the columns you want and then populate it for the rest of the participants. It's also very simple in SPSS, you would just compute a new variable and then make it equal to var(item1,item2,item3). But in R, I can't get it to work. So essentially, this is what I want my r data-frame to end up looking like:

[The end goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIh8g.png)

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to R and to StackOverflow.  When you type `??"standard deviation"` R will show you a list of functions matching the search term, here "standard deviation" (in quotes as it contains a space).  One of those is `sd` in the (base) package `stats`.  Doing `?sd` will then show you its help, and `example(sd)` will run the example(s) from that help page.  This should get you on the right way...

Comment: Another request: can you please show us a [mcve]? You could do that by reading the data you showed us into R (with `read.csv()` or `readxl::read_excel()`) and then using `dput()` to put the data into a useful format (then paste the results into your answer as text in a code block). Something *approximately* like `apply(my_data[,3:5], 1, sd)` will do what you want

Comment: You said you "can't get it to work".  Can you edit your question to include the code you've tried?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to calculate the std dev of rows of participants you could use the `apply` function on your dataframe.  If you want to use only certain columns to calculate the std dev, you can specify those in the `apply` dataframe parameter.  You can also directly append the std dev calculation vector to your dataframe.  All in one line of code. Here's how it works using the sample dataframe `mtcars`.  Let's limit the columns used to col# 1, 3, 6.  Then:

```
mtcars$sd <- apply(mtcars[, c(1, 3, 6)], 1, sd)
head(mtcars)
                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb        sd
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4  86.04968
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4  85.96296
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1  56.04571
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1 142.14174
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2 201.59927
Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1 123.89640
```

You can see the std devs were calculated and a new column `sd` was attached to the dataframe.